# python: opening text files as lists, and retrieving data with them

Tags: python, list, random, python-3.x

I am having problems with opening and using text files as lists in python...I need to use the string values in a text file(50 words in each), three text files...And I need to use a random word from each text file in an order to create an insult each time....(Shakespearian insults for those who know)

```
  import random #Import my random

Column_picker = random.randint(0, 45) #Define my random between 0-50

with open("Column1.txt") as d:
    insults1 = list(d)

with open("Column2.txt") as f:
    insults2 = list(f)

with open("Column3.txt") as e:
    insults3 = list(e)

print("Thou", insults1[], insults2[], insults3[])
```

That is what I have so far, and I feel really close I just cannot grab the right strings from the list..it either grabs the whole list or just a letter from it....

Comment: what's `insults1[]`, this is invalid!

Comment: Files are iterable in python.  Aside from that though, you want to avoid opening the file each time you run the program.  Write a command to open the text file and store them in a variable, and then pass that variable to your program.

Comment: How are the words separated in the file? Is each on a separate line?

Answer (score 3):

Use [random.choice](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.choice):

```
import random

def random_word(filename):
    with open(filename) as file:
         return random.choice(file.readlines())

filenames = ["file.txt", "another.txt"]
print("Thou " + ' '.join(map(random_word, filenames)))
```

You could also use [`linecache.getline(filename, line_number)`](http://docs.python.org/library/linecache.html) if you need to get lines multiple times.

Comment: blast, your `random_word` picker is better than mine.

Comment: @EMS -- I think `random.choice(x)` is much easier to read than `x[randint(0,len(x))]`.  It's way more explicit.  It almost reads like english -- I want to randomly *choose* an element from x.

Comment: @EMS: yes. "I need to use a random word from each text file" might be ambiguous. btw, one the advantages of using `random.choice` is that you avoid off-by-one errors such as in your code: `randint(0, len(x))` that can produce `IndexError`

Answer (score 0):

I assume each insult is a line in the file, but we can replace `readlines` with `readlines[0].split()` if they are space delimited on the first line, and we can add a bit to ignore `\n`, etc. But the idea is still the same.

```
import random #Import my random

Column_picker = random.randint(0, 45) #Define my random between 0-50
with open("Column1.txt") as d:
    insults1 = d.readlines()

with open("Column2.txt") as f:
    insults2 = f.readlines()

with open("Column3.txt") as e:
    insults3 = e.readlines()

print("Thou", insults1[Column_picker], insults2[Column_picker], insults3[Column_picker])
```

Comment: It keeps giving me the error (Index error: list index out of range), this is probably my fault with the text file..is there a specific way the words have to be written other than "word", "word", "word",

Comment: You should post a sample of your word file's contents so we know how it's organized. You might have to split on the commas and then remove the quotes or something. It all depends on how your data is organized.

Answer (score 0):

definitely better with a funcition:

```
def random_word(fname):
    line_num = random.randint(0, 45)
    with open(fname) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    return lines[line_num]

print("Thou",
     random_word("Column1.txt"),
     random_word("Column2.txt"),
     random_word("Column3.txt"))
```

The last line can even be a little cleaner:

```
files = ['Column1.txt','Column2.txt','Column3.txt']
insults = [random_word(f) for f in files]
print ( "Thou "+' '.join(insults) )
```

Comment: If you want the same index from each file, you'll need to move the random call out and then pass it to the function.

Comment: @EMS -- True.  But that doesn't seem as much fun.  Then you only have 50 total insults to hurl.  This way you have 50**3 insults which is a lot better :)